# I'm trying to get movement on an 8x8 board on console application using a switch

Tags: c#, console, switch-statement

I'm trying to be able to move a player round on an 8x8 board, I have up movement but I can't seem to get the other directions, please help, beginner here

```
static void MovePlayer(int playerNo, int distance, char direction)
{
 Console.WriteLine("Making a move for " + players[playerNo].Name);

 switch (direction)
{
 case 'U':
 // Moving the player up - need to decrease the value of Y
 // because the origin is the top left hand corner of the board
 players[playerNo].Y = players[playerNo].Y - distance;
 // This might take us off the top of the board, so we need to
 // wrap round
 if (players[playerNo].Y < 0)
 {
 players[playerNo].Y = players[playerNo].Y + 8;
 }
 break;

 case 'D': //down
 players[playerNo].Y = players[playerNo].Y - distance;
 // need to move down - increase Y
 if (players[playerNo].Y > 0)
 {
 players[playerNo].Y = players[playerNo].Y - 8;
 }
 break;
 case 'L':
 players[playerNo].Y = players[playerNo].Y - distance;
 break;

 case 'R':
 break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a 2D array that your tracking the player on? Either way, you need two coords of course. X and Y. But really, you should think of Row versus Column. For a game I am working on, I am doing almost the exact same thing here. I however, only allow the player one square advancement per turn.

If we say that X is the Row and Y is the column, to move up, you must subtract from X, to move down, you must add to X, to move right, you must subtract from Y and to move left you must add to Y.

I am assuming you are using distance to increment the position of the player. You are subtracting them in every case. So, for down, you need to add distance. And so on.